# Seaborn tsplot change labels on x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm passing tsplot a list of lists (say with 31 items in each of the lists) and it shows x-axis labels of 0 to 31.

How can I make it instead show -15 to 15?

Example from [the tutorial](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/tutorial/timeseries_plots.html), if its necessary:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(9221999)
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats, optimize
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(palette="Set2")

def sine_wave(n_x, obs_err_sd=1.5, tp_err_sd=.3):
    x = np.linspace(0, (n_x - 1) / 2, n_x)
    y = np.sin(x) + np.random.normal(0, obs_err_sd) + np.random.normal(0, tp_err_sd, n_x)
    return y

sines = np.array([sine_wave(31) for _ in range(20)])
sns.tsplot(sines);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
ax = sns.tsplot(sines);                      # capture axis
n = len(ax.xaxis.get_ticklabels())           # count labels
ax.set_xticklabels(np.linspace(-15, 15, n))  # set new tick labels
```

**Edit:** The previous solution is the generic matplotlib's way of manipulating the tick labels. As suggested by seaborn's creator @mwaskom you can also do:

```
sns.tsplot(sines, time=np.linspace(-15, 15, sines.shape[1]))
```

[image]

Comment: Yep, although you can also pass the ticklabels to the `time` argument of `tsplot`.